# GLSurfaceView NullPointerException

Tags: android, opengl-es

```
case R.id.btn_gamma:
        GPUImage mGPUImage = new GPUImage(this);
        mGPUImage.setGLSurfaceView((GLSurfaceView) findViewById(R.id.effectsview));
        mGPUImage.setImage(bm);
        mGPUImage.setFilter(new GPUImageBrightnessFilter(4.0f));
        imgPreview.setImageBitmap(bm);
```

**Xml:**

```
    <android.opengl.GLSurfaceView
    android:id="@+id/effectsview"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_weight="0.05" />
```

**Logcat:**

```
08-18 16:44:39.370: E/AndroidRuntime(23398): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-18 16:44:39.370: E/AndroidRuntime(23398): Process:
com.argenit.pathology, PID: 23398 08-18 16:44:39.370:
E/AndroidRuntime(23398): java.lang.NullPointerException 08-18
16:44:39.370: E/AndroidRuntime(23398):  at
android.opengl.GLSurfaceView.surfaceCreated(GLSurfaceView.java:531)
08-18 16:44:39.370: E/AndroidRuntime(23398):    at
android.view.SurfaceView.updateWindow(SurfaceView.java:601) 08-18
16:44:39.370: E/AndroidRuntime(23398):  at
android.view.SurfaceView.access$000(SurfaceView.java:94) 08-18
16:44:39.370: E/AndroidRuntime(23398):  at
android.view.SurfaceView$3.onPreDraw(SurfaceView.java:183) 08-18
16:44:39.370: E/AndroidRuntime(23398):  at
android.view.ViewTreeObserver.dispatchOnPreDraw(ViewTreeObserver.java:879)
08-18 16:44:39.370: E/AndroidRuntime(23398):    at
android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:2126)
08-18 16:44:39.370: E/AndroidRuntime(23398):    at
android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1226) 08-18
16:44:39.370: E/AndroidRuntime(23398):  at
android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6362)
08-18 16:44:39.370: E/AndroidRuntime(23398):    at
android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:803)
08-18 16:44:39.370: E/AndroidRuntime(23398):    at
android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:603) 08-18
16:44:39.370: E/AndroidRuntime(23398):  at
android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:573) 08-18
16:44:39.370: E/AndroidRuntime(23398):  at
android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:789)
08-18 16:44:39.370: E/AndroidRuntime(23398):    at
android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733) 08-18
16:44:39.370: E/AndroidRuntime(23398):  at
android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 08-18
16:44:39.370: E/AndroidRuntime(23398):  at
android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:157) 08-18 16:44:39.370:
E/AndroidRuntime(23398):    at
android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5350) 08-18
16:44:39.370: E/AndroidRuntime(23398):  at
java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 08-18
16:44:39.370: E/AndroidRuntime(23398):  at
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 08-18 16:44:39.370:
E/AndroidRuntime(23398):    at
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1265)
08-18 16:44:39.370: E/AndroidRuntime(23398):    at
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1081) 08-18
16:44:39.370: E/AndroidRuntime(23398):  at
dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

**Additional info full xml:**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="com.argenit.pathology.MainActivity" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imgPreview"
        android:scaleType="matrix"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_marginBottom="128dp"
        android:src="@drawable/logo" />

    <!--  ANA MENÜ BAŞLANGIÇ -->
    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/toolbar_main_menu"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="64dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="128dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:background="#cc1e252d"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/lyt_main_menu"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
            android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
            android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
            android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:paddingLeft="60dp"
                    android:paddingRight="60dp"
                    android:id="@+id/txtDosyalar"
                    android:text="@string/dosyalar"
                    android:textColor="#68ce30"
                    android:textColorHighlight="#000000"
                    android:textSize="20sp"
                    android:clickable="true" /> 

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:paddingLeft="60dp"
                    android:paddingRight="60dp"
                    android:id="@+id/txtObjektifler"
                    android:text="@string/objektifler"
                    android:textColor="#fff"
                    android:textColorHighlight="#000000"
                    android:textSize="20sp"
                    android:clickable="true" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:paddingLeft="60dp"
                    android:paddingRight="60dp"
                    android:id="@+id/txtEfektler"
                    android:text="@string/efektler"
                    android:textColor="#fff"
                    android:textColorHighlight="#000000"
                    android:textSize="20sp"
                    android:clickable="true" />

            </LinearLayout>

    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
    <!--  ANA MENÜ BİTİŞ -->


        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            android:id="@+id/toolbar_effect_details"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="64dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="128dp"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:background="#cc1e252d"
            android:visibility="gone"
            android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize" >

            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/lytFooterTop_details"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

                    <ImageButton
                        android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackground"
                        android:id="@+id/btn_closeEffect"
                        android:onClick="btn_closeEffect_Click"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:padding="10dip"
                        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                        android:src="@drawable/close"
                        android:scaleType="centerInside"
                        android:adjustViewBounds="true" />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:id="@+id/txt_effect"
                        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                        android:textColorHighlight="#000000"
                        android:textSize="24sp"
                        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                        android:layout_centerVertical="true" />

                    <ImageButton
                        android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackground"
                        android:id="@+id/btn_saveEffect"
                        android:onClick="btn_saveEffect_Click"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:padding="10dip"
                        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                        android:src="@drawable/tick"
                        android:scaleType="centerInside"
                        android:adjustViewBounds="true" />
                </RelativeLayout>

        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            android:id="@+id/toolbar_effects_footer"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="128dp"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:background="#1e252d"
            android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize" >

            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/lytFooterBottom_details"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/imgOverview"
                    android:layout_width="250dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:background="@android:color/white"
                    android:visibility="gone" />

                <SeekBar
                    android:id="@+id/seekBarObjectives"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:progressDrawable="@drawable/red_scrubber_progress"
                    android:thumb="@drawable/red_scrubber_control"
                    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:layout_marginLeft = "550dp"
                    android:visibility="gone" />

                <!--  MAIN MENU DOSYALAR ALT MENUSU BAŞLANGIÇ -->
                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/lyt_dosyalar_altmenu"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
                    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
                    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
                    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">

                    <ImageButton
                            android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackground"
                            android:id="@+id/btn_fileOpen"
                            android:onClick="btn_fileOpen_Click"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:paddingLeft="30dp"
                            android:paddingRight="30dp"
                            android:src="@drawable/file_open" />

                    <ImageButton
                            android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackground"
                            android:id="@+id/btn_saveScreenshot"
                            android:onClick="btn_saveScreenshot_Click"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:paddingLeft="30dp"
                            android:paddingRight="30dp"
                            android:src="@drawable/save_screenshot" />

                    <ImageButton
                            android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackground"
                            android:id="@+id/btn_settings"
                            android:onClick="btn_settings_Click"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:paddingLeft="30dp"
                            android:paddingRight="30dp"
                            android:src="@drawable/settings" />

                </LinearLayout>
                <!--  MAIN MENU DOSYALAR ALT MENUSU BİTİŞ -->

                <!--  MAIN MENU OBJEKTİFLER ALT MENUSU BAŞLANGIÇ -->
                <LinearLayout 
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="25dp"
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:layout_marginTop="90dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft = "290dp"
                    android:id="@+id/lyt_objektifler_altmenu"
                    android:visibility="gone">

                    <TextView
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:text="Fit"
                            android:textSize="16dp"
                            android:textColor="#ffffff"/>

                    <TextView
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:text="1.25X"
                            android:textSize="16dp"
                            android:textColor="#ffffff"
                            android:layout_marginLeft="80dp"/>

                    <TextView
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:textSize="16dp"
                            android:text="10X"
                            android:textColor="#ffffff"
                            android:layout_marginLeft="80dp"/>
                    <TextView
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"     
                            android:textSize="16dp"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:text="20X"
                            android:textColor="#ffffff"
                            android:layout_marginLeft="80dp"/>

                    <TextView
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:textSize="16dp"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:text="40X"
                            android:textColor="#ffffff"
                            android:layout_marginLeft="80dp"/>

                    <TextView
                            android:textSize="16dp"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:text="63X"
                            android:textColor="#ffffff"
                            android:layout_marginLeft="80dp"/>

                    <TextView
                            android:textSize="16dp"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:text="100X"
                            android:textColor="#ffffff"
                            android:layout_marginLeft="80dp"/>

                </LinearLayout>
                <!--  MAIN MENU OBJEKTİFLER ALT MENUSU BİTİŞ -->

                <!--  MAIN MENU EFEKTLER ALT MENUSU BAŞLANGIÇ -->
                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/lyt_efektler_altmenu"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
                    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
                    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
                    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:visibility="gone" >

                    <ImageButton
                        android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackground"
                        android:id="@+id/btn_gamma"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:paddingLeft="30dp"
                        android:paddingRight="30dp"
                        android:src="@drawable/gamma" />

                    <ImageButton
                        android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackground"
                        android:id="@+id/btn_contrast"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:paddingLeft="30dp"
                        android:paddingRight="30dp"
                        android:src="@drawable/contrast" />

                    <ImageButton
                        android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackground"
                        android:id="@+id/btn_sharpen"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:paddingLeft="30dp"
                        android:paddingRight="30dp"
                        android:src="@drawable/sharpen" />

                    <ImageButton
                        android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackground"
                        android:id="@+id/btn_opacity"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:paddingLeft="30dp"
                        android:paddingRight="30dp"
                        android:src="@drawable/opacity" />

                    <ImageButton
                                android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackground"
                                android:id="@+id/btn_default"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:paddingLeft="30dp"
                                android:paddingRight="30dp"
                                android:src="@drawable/default_effect" />
                </LinearLayout> 
                <!--  MAIN MENU EFEKTLER ALT MENUSU BİTİŞ -->


                <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:id="@+id/txtImgName"
                        android:text="Dosya Seçilmedi."
                        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                        android:textColorHighlight="#000000"
                        android:textSize="10sp"
                        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" />

            </RelativeLayout>               

    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/toolbar_seekbarEffect"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="128dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:background="#1e252d"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize" >

            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/lytFooter_seekbar"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:paddingLeft="100dp"
                android:paddingRight="100dp"
                android:gravity="center" >

                    <SeekBar
                        android:id="@+id/seekBar"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:progressDrawable="@drawable/red_scrubber_progress"
                        android:thumb="@drawable/red_scrubber_control" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/seekBar_Value"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                        android:textColorHighlight="#000000"
                        android:textSize="14sp" />

            </RelativeLayout>

    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/loadingBar"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleLarge"
        android:layout_width="70dp"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:indeterminate="true"
        android:indeterminateDrawable="@drawable/custom_loading"
        android:visibility="gone" />

     <android.opengl.GLSurfaceView
    android:id="@+id/effectsview"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_weight="0.05" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: It wasn't me. But perhaps it has too much code and... no description aside from the title.

Comment: @Mauker no need to description, when i set the glsurfaceview via findviewbyid, i got the nullpointerexception

Comment: Are you using the correct reference on the `setContentView` method?

Comment: I downvoted because of the missing information. For example there was no hint on which line of the posted code the exception happens. Nice that you now tell it in a comment, but that's one of the most important things here.

Comment: @Mauker yes i am using activity_main. BDL thanks for comment, of course you can vote down but i just want to know why ? now ok

Comment: Can you post your full xml please?

Comment: @Mauker i added, last is surfaceview

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, don't use `fill_parent`, it's deprecated. Use `match_parent` instead.

Now on your code, try to change this:

```
GPUImage mGPUImage = new GPUImage(this);
mGPUImage.setGLSurfaceView((GLSurfaceView) findViewById(R.id.effectsview));
```

To this:

```
GPUImage mGPUImage = new GPUImage(this);
GLSurfaceView glView = (GLSurfaceView) this.findViewById(R.id.effectsview);
glView.setRenderer(this); // "this" refers to a renderer. I'm assuming your class implements it.
mGPUImage.setGLSurfaceView(glView);
```

Comment: also no need to setRenderer, thanks for helping. :)))